# EmberJS model ordering

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Given

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('foos')
},
```

In an Ember route how would I reverse the order of the records for display purposes?

i.e. in my template I have:

```
{{#each model as |foo|}}
```

and they are currently showing up in the exact opposite order that I would want.

Comment: Calling `reverse` or `sort`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways to do this. One is to create a computed property on the controller.

```
sortedModel: Ember.computed('model.[]', function() {
  return this.get('model').toArray().sort( (a, b) => {
    return whateverSortYouWantToDo
  })
})
```

Then in your template

```
{{#each sortedModel as |foo|}}
```

Comment: I ended up putting the computed in a component, but this got me most of the way there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arrayProxy implementing sortableMixin defined in your controller and use this property in your template. For example :

```
sortedContent: function(){
    var self = this;
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
        sortProperties: ['modelPropertyYouWantToSort'],
        sortAscending: true,
        content: self.get('model')
    });
}.property('model')
```

Template :

```
{{#each sortedContent as |foo|}}
```